# Identification of the dagger/mini sword which has been in my family for as long as I can remember (and I am 80 years old)

Tags: identification

I don't know anything of its provenance and the handle is probably not original.  The blade is 14.75 inches (37.5 cm) long from tip to the start of the handle. Although I am not an expert, the marking on the blade appears to indicate that it is made of forged steel.

[image: Image of dagger/short sword to be identified]

Comment: If you've got access to the weapon, a higher-resolution photo, a photo of the other side, and an object for scale purposes might be helpful as well. Someone might be able to get you something without that stuff, but that's what I'd do if I wanted to maximize my chances of success on this question.

Comment: Bummer that I can't see that picture from work (where I am).

Answer (score 14):

This would be a *straight* example of a *keris* or [kris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kris) dagger from the region of Indonesia. The typical blade in this form is wavy, but straight ones can be seen on various sites such as [this discussion](http://www.vikingsword.com/vb/showthread.php?t=7333) at vikingsword.com.

You can see both straight and wavy ones on this image from Thomas Stamford Raffles (1781-1826)  [The History of Java Volume I](https://books.google.com/books?id=R7FjAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=history%20of%20java&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjPm5_m_ZD-AhUXKEQIHa5nBGwQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=history%20of%20java&f=false).(1817)

[image].

Comment: That was the first thing I hit on too. WP has a picture with [lots more styles here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/94/Raffles_Varieties_of_the_Javan_Kris.png), but that shape up near the hilt seems pretty distinctive.

Comment: Given how utilitarian it looks, my next SWAG would be that it was a quickly-produced commoner's or soldier's kris.